# Merging relationship direction dependent on parameters

Tags: parameters, neo4j, relation, direction

I'm having a map list like:

```
rels: [{"nodeid":14, "direction":false}, {"nodeid":15, "direction":true}]
```

I'd like to create relationships between the created node and the given nodes with the respective direction:

```
CREATE (n) WITH n
UNWIND {rels} AS rel
    MATCH (p) WHERE ID(p)=rel.nodeid
WITH n, p
    CASE
         WHEN rel.direction=false THEN
             MERGE (n)-[:test]->(p)
         ELSE
             MERGE (n)<-[:test]-(p)
    END
RETURN id(n)
```

yields:

> Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 5, column 11 (offset: 108))
>   "        CASE"
>              ^

```
CREATE (n%-(:%s%) {properties})
WITH n
UNWIND {rels} AS rel MATCH (p) WHERE ID(p)=rel.nodeid
WITH n,p
MERGE 
    (CASE 
        WHEN rel.direction=true THEN (p)<-[:test]-(n)
        ELSE (p)-[:test1]->(n)
    END)
```

yields:

> Invalid input 'W': expected whitespace, comment, node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 5, column 33 (offset: 174))
>   "                    MERGE (CASE WHEN

How would I accomplish this?

## EDIT:

What I have so far:

```
CREATE (n {properties})
            WITH n,
            filter(x IN {rels} WHERE x.direction = true) AS outs,
            filter(x IN {rels} WHERE x.direction = false) AS ins
            UNWIND outs as out
                 OPTIONAL MATCH (o) WHERE ID(o)=out.id
                 FOREACH ( y IN CASE WHEN o IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
                     MERGE (n)-[:test]->(o) )
            WITH n, ins
            UNWIND ins as in
                 OPTIONAL MATCH (i) WHERE ID(i)=in.id
                 FOREACH ( y IN CASE WHEN i IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
                     MERGE (n)<-[:test]-(i) )
            RETURN id(n)
```

The `RETURN id(n)` works only when `ins` and `outs` is not empty. And if multiple elements exist in `ins` or `outs` it returns `id(n)` `length(ins)*length(outs)` times, which is not really what is needed.

So: How to return `id(n)` in all cases and only once?

## EDIT2:

I'm now using a `CASE` in `UNWIND` so it is guaranteed to return the created node ID even if `{rels}` is empty.
Also `LIMIT 1` in the return statement guarantees only one row to be returned.

```
CREATE (n {properties})
            WITH n,
            filter(x IN {rels} WHERE x.direction = true) AS outs,
            filter(x IN {rels} WHERE x.direction = false) AS ins
            UNWIND (CASE WHEN length(outs) > 0 THEN outs ELSE [{id:-1}] END) as out
                 OPTIONAL MATCH (o) WHERE ID(o)=out.id
                 FOREACH ( y IN CASE WHEN o IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
                     MERGE (n)-[r:child]->(o))
            WITH n, ins
            UNWIND (CASE WHEN length(ins) > 0 THEN ins ELSE [{id:-1}] END) as in
                 OPTIONAL MATCH (i) WHERE ID(i)=in.id
                 FOREACH ( y IN CASE WHEN i IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
                     MERGE (n)<-[r:child]-(i) )
            RETURN id(n) LIMIT 1
```

Pretty sure this is not perfect, but it's doing the job.

Comment: Sounds like you need `WITH DISTINCT n` before your RETURN.

Comment: I've now used `RETURN id(n) LIMIT 1` instead as I'd assume it uses less resources!?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two distinct collections from your initial `rels` collection and UNWIND them, a simple example :

```
WITH [{id:14, direction:false},{id:15, direction:true}] AS rels 
CREATE (n:Node) 
WITH n,
filter(x IN rels WHERE x.direction = true) AS outs, 
filter(x IN rels WHERE x.direction = false) AS ins 
UNWIND outs as out 
MERGE (o:Node {id: out.id}) 
MERGE (o)-[:OUT]->(n) 
WITH n, ins UNWIND ins AS in 
MERGE (i:Node {id: in.id}) 
MERGE (i)<-[:IN]-(n)
```

Test it here :

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=iv5opz

[image]

Comment: Works great! Any way I can use `return ID(n)` successfully even if an id in rels does not exist? Currently it fails whenever `outs` or `ins` has only non-existing nodes. (I'm using `MATCH (o) WHERE ID(o)=out.id` because I don't want to create it in case it doesn't exist).

Comment: The problem with this is that `UNWIND` will cause the `return ID(n)` statement to be called `length(o) * length(i)` times. And if `o` and `i` are 0 then nothing is returned!